# Android - Viewmodel getting larger

Tags: java, android, kotlin, architecture

Hi am using viewmodel in my application. Since my logic is large in single activity. Am implementing that logic in my viewmodel. Anyway i want to separate this logic from my viewmodel. Any idea how to segregate the logic out my from my viewmodel.

Comment: move some of your logic to repository

Comment: @Sergey no it is ui logic.

Comment: Hi @user11028801 can you provide an example of such logic?

Comment: @user11028801 https://erikcaffrey.github.io/content/images/2016/1/android_archi.png you can use clean architecture create layers data,presentation,domain and divide your logic

Comment: You can use *multiple viewmodels* if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's UI logic, you can isolate each piece of code that has to do with the same behavior (or even UI section) into its own fragment/view and corresponding view model (think Single Responsibility Principle). If it makes sense, you can also share view models between the same UI components. Then, you orchestrate everything in the activity. For code that has nothing to do with the Android framework, you can also extract it to its own independent class, and then use it in the view model through composition.